# Cocoa display Push Notification in Dock

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, push, apple-push-notifications

i have set up a little test application for push notifications. this is my actual didRecieveRemoteNotification function

```
-(void)application:(NSApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [[NSApp dockTile] setBadgeLabel:@"1"];
    NSLog(@"%@ with payload = %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), userInfo);
}
```

So how do i get this kind of "badge" itunes has got when setting:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock itunes-notifications -bool TRUE
```

something like this image (sorry i am new and can't post images) [image](http://thomas.guenzel-ag.de/big_files/dock.png)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to get the screen coordinate of the dock item using `dockTile.contentView.window.frame.origin` and positioning a new borderless `NSWindow` as a childWindow to that dockTile's contentView's window.